# Automator: shell script for files in a folder

Tags: shell, terminal, automator

I'm trying to create an easy App with Automator, this app needs to merge all the txt files in a specific folder into one csv file. This is the script:

```
cat *.txt >merged.csv
```

This works fine if I open terminal, move to the folder containing the files and execute it.

I'd like if possible to make it work as an app where I drag the folder on the App Icon and the merged file is then created in the folder. Then show a notification of the completed work.

I tried this:

[image]

But it gives me an error in the shell (while in terminal works fine).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `Run Shell Script` action to pass input `as arguments` - then the path of the currently selected Finder item(s) will be passed as `$1` (...).

In your shell script, you then need to change (`cd "$1"`) to the passed-in folder in order to perform your merge command in the right place.

I suggest you make your shell script more robust to ensure that (a) only a *folder* is passed in (as currently selected in Finder) and (b) just *one* item:

```
# Make sure that a _single folder_ is currently selected in Finder; exit otherwise.
[[ $# -eq 1 && -d "$1" ]] || 
  { osascript -e 'display alert "Please select a single folder."'; exit 1; }

# Change to the folder.
cd "$1" || exit

# Perform the merge command.
cat *.txt >merged.csv
```

Comment: Tks that solved it! I just changed `exit 0` instead of `exit 1` so I don't get the automator error in addition to the alert. Tks a lot!